# use an inline javascript function (not jquery) on drupal 7 

Tags: 7, javascript

This is how jQuery is included in d7

```
(function ($) {
  // jquey codes here  
})(jQuery);
```

How i can include javascript code (not jquery) in d7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to write a plain JavaScript instead of JQuery, You can proceed with normal function declaration like

```
function sample() {
}
```

and go ahead. It is normal way of the doing things in javascript, More over jQuery is a framework of javascript and as said you can add js files in the traditional way

```
drupal_add_js()
```

Comment: It's worth noting that Drupal uses behaviors for attaching (and removing) JS - see Chapabu's answer for an example and further reading.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery is just a JavaScript library, so you can include plain JS inside the jQuery wrapper and it'll work fine.  All the wrapper does is allow you to use the `$` sign for jQuery instead of having to write `jQuery('.xyz')`.

See the following example - standard JS inside a Drupal behaviour.

```
(function ($) {

  Drupal.behaviors.exampleModule = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      var ip = '<!--#echo var="REMOTE_ADDR"-->';
      alert("Your IP address is" + ip);
    }
  };

})(jQuery);
```

The [Managing JavaScript in Drupal](http://drupal.org/node/756722) handbook page has LOADS of useful information about JavaScript in Drupal, it's definitely worth a read.

Answer (score 2):

This is how jQuery is included so you can use the $ symbol. But you can write any piece of js code in that file without this part:

```
(function ($) {
  // jquey codes here  
})(jQuery);
```

But to include files, you can simply use `drupal_add_js()` in code, `scripts[] = script.js` in `your_module.info` or use `$form['#attached']['js'][] = 'script.js'` in a form array.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by implementing [`drupal_add_js()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) in your custom module.

```
<?php
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme') .'/mytheme.js');
?>
```

Also you can add the files in your `MODULE.info` file by adding
`scripts[] = youjsfile.js`